# TSQL if statement within

Tags: t-sql

I have 160 columns like below

```
name,preweight,postweight,prebp,postbp,presugar,postsugar...
```

I am trying to include new column at the end for the list of factors (like weight is different between pre and post, sugar is different pre and post.).

Written sql like below

```
select name,preweight,postweight,prebp,postbp,presugar,postsugar
case
when (preweight!=postweight)
then 'weight changed'
when (presugar!=postsugar)
then 'sugar changed'
end
from clientinfo
```

now always shows one changed. but how I can list all the factors which are changed?

Comment: For the record, this is a horrible data model, and if you do what you're proposing, you're responsible for making it worse. Stop treating a database table as though it's a spreadsheet. It is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `concat_ws()` and a series of `case` expressions:

```
select 
    name,
    preweight,
    postweight,
    prebp,
    postbp,
    presugar,
    postsugar 
    concat_ws(
        ', '
        case when preweight <> postweight then 'weight changed' end,
        case when prebp     <> postbp     then 'bp changed'     end,
        case when presugar  <> postsugar  then 'sugar changed'  end
    ) what_changed
from clientinfo
```